# Powerline Networking Surge protection and electrical interference?

Tags: networking, powerline-networking, interference, surge-protection

The manufacturer advice is to plug them straight into the wall socket and not through power boards or adapters. However where I live (sub tropical) we have frequent electrical storms and power goes out once or twice per year.  I always pull everything from the wall, but when I'm not home...

So instead I have used 4 of these for 2 years now through surge protected power boards - and they work fine - but perhaps i'm not getting the maximum throughput.

Now I've upgraded 2 of them from Netgear AV500 to 1000 for more speed and to match the AC wifi Router - and to get best signal (old house, not great wiring) they are plugged straight into the wall now.

Do you know if I am in danger of frying these $150 units!  Should I go back to surge protected power boards adapters?  I think you can get surge protection for ethernet also...

Also when the washing machine is on, I do notice the throughput goes down and sometimes can even temporarily stop the network signal. Is there something I can put on the washing machine power plug or the powerline plugs to "clean" the power interference?

Comment: There's *supposed* to be standalone filters for things like washing machines, but they're strange beasts I have never seen before.  I'd also note that *all* units in a homeplug AV network default to the speed of the slowest unit on the network.

Comment: ok so mixing the speeds isn't going to work. Ill sell the slower ones then.

ill do some research and see if i can track down some kind of power filter for the washing machine. Thanks for letting me know it isn't a crazy idea. just occurred to me that it was feasible.

Ill try contacting Netgear to see if they can tell me if the plugs have any surge protection built in. You'd assume they would advertise this fact though if they did.

Comment: I just moved mine, which did the trick.

Comment: Where are any numbers to justify such emotional fears.  Power outages (a voltage from 120 volts to zero) is not a surge (120 volts rises to thousands of volts).  Power outages do not damage any appliance.     If fear is justified, then you have been replacing surge damaged dimmer switches, furnace, smoke detectors, dishwashers, door bell, refrigerator, bathroom and kitchen GFCIs, etc how many times every month?  All appliances already have robust protection.  That is totally unknown when emotion replaces specification numbers.  How many other unprotected appliances were destroyed? None?